# Does Solr 7.x have support for Java 11?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, solr, spring-data-solr

Currently our applications runs with Spring Data Solr + Apache Solr 5.3 + Java 8

We are upgrading our systems to Java 11. Does Spring Data Solr & Apache Solr latest version support Java 11 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solr 7.6 [supports "Java 8 or greater"](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/7_6_0/SYSTEM_REQUIREMENTS.html). However . . . .

- As per the [Solr News](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/news.html) it looks like 10 is tested and supported
- Java is generally backwards compatible although Java 11 release notes might suggest has some [backwards compatibility issues](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/11-relnote-issues-5012449.html) that might trip folks up in general
- [This ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-12809)  in the Solr Apache JIRA indicates that "Upgrading to a more recent Java (JDK 11?)" is open and unresolved
- More definitively: As of late 2018, Java 11 was not yet recommended according to the good folks at [LucidWorks](https://support.lucidworks.com/s/question/0D52E00004cEamJSAS/is-solr-73-andor-higher-compatible-with-java-11). "The recommendation is to stay with JDK-8 until the Apache project officially supports JDK-11."

Based on the above it sounds like Java 8 is the safe bet, 10 might work but is risky and 11 is "right out" (h/t to Monty Python and the Holy Grail)