# Solr 6.6.1 Java Support

Tags: solr

Does Solr 6.6.1 support Java JRE 11?  I've done some research and some posts it seems say it does, while other says there is a bug.  We are using it with JRE 8 without issues but our IT department wants us on a later version of Java.

Comment: Probably the same answer as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54350573/does-solr-7-x-have-support-for-java-11

Comment: Thank you.  I had seen that post but figured I would ask to see if anyone had additional information.

Comment: Since Solr 7 doesn't have JRE 11 support I can't imagine it's likely or even possible that Solr 6 does.